# Authentication issue in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to access a route in laravel. It's working fine for the below scenario

```
Route::get('/signup', function() {
    return View::make('signup');
});
```

But it's not working when I am trying to access  via controller.

```
Route::get('/signup', 'signupController@signup');
```

Below is the content of my signupController file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use View;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class signupController extends Controller {

    public function signup()
    {                   
        $view = View::make('signup');
        return $view;
    }


}
```

I am getting the below error
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Find my route.php file content

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/signup', 'signupController@signup');
```

Comment: The code should work as it is, the error has to be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be?

```
Route::get('/signup', ['uses' => 'signupController@signup']);
```

I don't see any other reason.

Comment: and the error message is the same? maybe you have errors in other part of your routes.php - could you edit your question and provide the routes.php content?